# Slow opening of calendar items

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, calendar

I've bought an HTC Desire HD yesterday with Android 2.2 Froyo and HTC Sense. So I migrated my calendar items manually and it seemed to pick up some connections from my Facebook and my Twitter, which was nice..

But:

From time to time the calendar app just becomes really really slow for some reason, the sync icon is running, and the items just won't open. When this happens I keep staring at a blank screen for about 20 seconds which is really annoying...

When I check out what he is syncing its always either Facebook, or the Google calendar.

I already tried to switch these things off, but it does not seem to help :( ...

It even goes to the point where the whole calendar app just crashes, or even takes HTC Sense with it..

How can I make the calendar fast?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hard reset gave me the solution..

Comment: I have this very same issue, why is a hard reset considered a "solution"?  That doesn't go anywhere near telling us WHY nor HOW the problem occured...?

Comment: True, but until there is a better answer, it will be your only option I'm afraid..

Answer (score 1):

Settings >> Applications >> Manage applications and selected "Clear cache" and "Clear data" for (where applicable)

Comment: Pretty standard steps for dealing with a truculent app.